# Yii 2 RBAC Exception 'yii\base\UnknownMethodException' with message 'Calling unknown method: yii\rbac\DbManager::getItem()'

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

I was trying to create a console command for yii 2 rbac I'm getting 
exception:

> 'yii\base\UnknownMethodException' with message 'Calling unknown
>   method: yii\rbac\DbManager::getItem()'

```
 protected function createItem($name,$type,$description='',$data=null)
{
$item=$this->_authManager->getItem($name);
if($item===null)
{
    $item = new Item;
    $item->name = $name;
    $item->type = $type;
    $item->description = $description;

    self::$newCount++;
    echo "creating new item $name \n";
    $item=$this->_authManager->addItem($item);
}
return $item;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yii2 DbManager Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager.html#getItem()-detail) - `getItem()` method is protected.

[PHP: Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) - check out here for visibility in PHP.

Comment: do you have any Idea why it was set as protected. in Yii 1.1 this was public                             public function createAuthItem($name,$type,$description='',$bizRule=null,$data=null);